# Difference between two versions in ClearCase dynamic view

Tags: clearcase

Say , I've two different dynamic views in ClearCase.

I would like to know if there is any command to give a report with:
"`x lines added , y lines deleted , z lines changed`" between two versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use [diffstat](http://invisible-island.net/diffstat/) to produce a very nice, visual "x lines added , y lines deleted , z lines changed" overview (1).

Here is an example of the output from comparing the two latest versions of diffstat:

```
$ diff -u diffstat-1.53 diffstat-1.54 | diffstat
 CHANGES    |   12 +++++++++++-
 diffstat.1 |    4 ++--
 diffstat.c |   57 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++------
 3 files changed, 64 insertions(+), 9 deletions(-)
```

In your case, run

```
diff -u /view/VIEW1/SOMEVOB/some/dir_or_file /view/VIEW2/SOMEVOB/some/dir_or_file | diffstat
```

---

(1) 
Actually "z lines changed" is impossible to determine without analysing the meaning of the lines (and a computer algorithm cannot do that). E.g. if the old line is `int x;` and the new line is `int y;`, is a) `x` changed to `y` or b) `x` removed and `y` added?

Comment: It looks good , but I'm not understaning how to use this file , I downloaded diffstat.tar file but it doesn't have any exe , do I need to do something more with the downladed tar file to work with the diff command?

Comment: The tar file is a archive of files, just like zip. The file contains the source code and you have to compile yourself. For windows a lot of unix programs are available precompiled from www.cygwin.com.

Answer (score 3):

As I commented earlier, you can use

```
cleartool diff -serial_format prog.c prog.c@@\main\4
```

This will format the difference to view the all line rather than just the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic views, you can use the [extended pathnames](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?ratlid=cctocbody&rs=984&uid=swg21220890) with **[cleartool diff](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_diff.htm)**.

This help page "[To compare with a version other than the predecessor](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.dev.doc/topics/cc_dev/t_compare_ver_other_pred.htm) " gives all the details:

```
cleartool diff prog.c prog.c@@\main\4
```

cleartool diff won't give you exactly what you want if you look only for a summary (displaying only the number of lines added, removed and changed):

> The default file-comparison report begins with a file summary, which lists all the input files and their assignments as `file 1`, `file 2`, and so on.
>   If no differences are detected among the files, this listing is replaced by the message Files are identical.
>
> The remainder of the report is a series of pairwise differences, each of which is preceded by a descriptive header line:

```
******************************** (file summary)
<<< file 1: util.c@@/main/1
>>> file 2: util.c@@/main/3
********************************
----------[after 15]------|-------[inserted 16]------ (header)
                          | char *s;        (difference)
                                                    |-
---------[changed 18]-----|----[changed to 19-21]---- (header)
return ctime(&clock);     | s = ctime(&clock); (difference)
                       -  | s[ strlen(s)-1 ] = '\0';
                          | return s;
                          |-
```

Note:

> report with x lines added , y lines deleted , z lines changed between two versions

No, not with `cleartool diff`: the diff format doesn't include a pure summary style.

**But since you can access to any two versions in a dynamic view, you can use any diff tool you want to achieve that particular output**.

Comment: Additionally you can use


cleartool diff -serial_format file file@@\main\branch\4

Answer (score 0):

[cleartool diff](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/836.html)