# how to find the number of lines which got changed from one label to another in clear case?

Tags: diff, clearcase

I would like to find the number of lines of code which got added/modified/deleted between two releases. I have a label which is applied at the end of release.

There is ClearCase Report Viewer which shows list of elements which got modified between two labels. But I am looking for number of files which got changed.

Any solution to this?

Comment: Number of files or number of lines?

Comment: I am able to see the change list between two labels using Cleacase Report Builder. Now, How can I find the number of lines which are  added/modified/deleted between two Labels? Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4334955/23118).

Comment: Notice that regarding *modified* lines, what you ask for is [impossible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38464406/23118).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way (without involving any commercial third-party tool) is to use linux commands [`diff`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/diff) and **[`diffstat`](http://invisible-island.net/diffstat/)** and apply it to two dynamic views, each one with their own config spec selecting a label:

```
element * LABELx
element * /main/LATEST
```

That way, you can get a full report of the differences between the two `diffstat` reports.
See "[Difference between two versions in ClearCase dynamic view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4355119/6309)" for a concrete example.

```
diff -u /view/VIEW1/SOMEVOB/some/dir /view/VIEW2/SOMEVOB/some/dir | diffstat
```

Note: this is valid for Windows as well, since [any Git distribution](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) includes `diff.exe`, and [diffstat is available for Windows](https://sourceforge.net/projects/diffstats/).